# Calculate the difference values with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the difference with conditions, how to do it?

`Source date`

```
    TimeStamp  Input  match   
 1      38563  aaaaa  False        
 2      38568    bbb  False        
 3      38577  aaaaa  False        
 4      38580    bbb  False        
 5      38589    bbb   True        
 6      38591  aaaaa  False
```

`expect result`

```
     TimeStamp  Input  match  diff 
 1      38563  aaaaa   False   NaN     
 2      38568    bbb   False   NaN    
 3      38577  aaaaa   False   NaN   
 4      38580    bbb   False   NaN    
 5      38589    bbb    True     1    
 6      38591  aaaaa   False   NaN
```

Comment: Not understand, there is only one `True`, so why value? In previous solution for one True was `NaN`

Comment: I want to calculate 'Pen' difference value,is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create groups by consecutive `True`s and pass to [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby((~df['match']).cumsum()[df['match']])['TimeStamp'].diff()
print (df)
   TimeStamp  match  diff
0      38269  False   NaN
1      38340   True   NaN
2      38341   True   1.0
3      38349   True   8.0
4      38350   True   1.0
5      38351  False   NaN
6      38358  False   NaN
7      38358   True   NaN
8      38366  False   NaN
9      38370  False   NaN
```

Comment: @ChenAndy - can you edit question?

Comment: update question already

Comment: @ChenAndy - Can you test `df.loc[df['match'], 'diff'] = df['TimeStamp'].diff()` ?

Comment: thanks you help but Index will be sorted incorrectly

Comment: @ChenAndy - hmmm, unfortunately not understand. Not underastand `Index will be sorted incorrectly` and also how is count `1` in output in question.

Comment: like this index 1,2,4,3,6,5

Comment: Sorry my question is so difficult to describe

Comment: @ChenAndy - is possible add more data and explain by data?

Comment: I found the reason, it was my fault

Comment: `df.loc[df['match'], 'diff'] = df['TimeStamp'].diff()` can also work